# (StreamWriter) The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process

Tags: c#, stream, streamwriter

Hi why dosent this work?

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
    int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
    sw.WriteLine(count.ToString());
}
```

I got this error message: "The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process."

So i figgured i had to put it like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}

using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
    sw.WriteLine(count.ToString());
}
```

But i get the same error. Iam so bad at this, someone please help me :)

Comment: where does the error occur? you would be better using `new StreamWriter(path)` (btw you know that the file now has 100 lines so why do you need to count?)

Comment: This is not the real code. Its alot more. But it crashes at File.ReadLines

Comment: Ok sure, then yes its because you are attemping to read a file that is already open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `ReadLines()` the file is already open due to the open `StreamWriter`.

You have to perform the actions sequentially:

```
        int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {            
            sw.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                }

            }

            int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {

                sw.WriteLine(count.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Using will dispose and close stream, no need to do it manually.

Comment: and has no explanation